# compare two dates undefined method `>' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to comparte two dates in my controller here is the code

```
if @user.payment.count == 0
    some action
elsif @user.payment.last.active_until.to_date > Time.now.to_date
    some action
elsif @user.payment.last.active_until.nil?
    some action
end
```

When I try to evaluate this

```
elsif @user.payment.last.active_until.to_date > Time.now.to_date
```

I get this error:

```
undefined method `>' for nil:NilClass
```

But I have the same line in a view to show some other information and it works great.

I don't understand why in the controller doesn't work.

Thanks in advance for your help.

---

UPDATE

here is my console output

```
1.9.3p286 :002 > u.payment.last.active_until
  Payment Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "payments".* FROM "payments" WHERE "payments"."user_id" = 10 ORDER BY "payments"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
 => Thu, 24 Jan 2013
```

If I compare this in my console I get this:

```
1.9.3p286 :003 > u.payment.last.active_until.to_date > Time.now.to_date
  Payment Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "payments".* FROM "payments" WHERE "payments"."user_id" = 10 ORDER BY "payments"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
 => true
```

---

UPDATE 2

the same if in my controller is true and in console is false, I thinks here is the problem

```
1.9.3p286 :010 > u.payment.last.active_until.nil?
  Payment Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "payments".* FROM "payments" WHERE "payments"."user_id" = 10 ORDER BY "payments"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
 => false
```

Comment: Did you check that @user.payment.last.active_until has a value?

Comment: Yes, it has..here is the value active_until: "2013-01-24"

Comment: Is there any active_until that are nil in your payments table? That is: `Payment.where(active_until: nil).all` Is that console output for the same user you have in @user?

Comment: No the user only have one record; yes is the same user

Answer (score 2):

Just reorder your statements, so the date is first checked for `nil?`:

```
if @user.payment.count == 0
  some action
elsif @user.payment.last.active_until.nil?
  some action
elsif @user.payment.last.active_until.to_date > Time.now.to_date
  some action
end
```

PS: Additionally, check that the `to_date` method doesn't return `nil` for non-`nil` objects.

Comment: I did, but them I only check until here elsif @user.payment.last.active_until.nil?

Comment: Karaktor, you were right, my problem is that @user.payment.last.active_until is empty, but If I check this in rails console, it has a date...I don't undertand why?

Comment: @Jean Are you using the same environment in console and for your server (i.e. the same database).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with `@user.payment.last.active_until`

You should do the check for `nil` before you try to access that field and you'll probably see that it's empty

A good habit I've created is that every time I access a chain method like that I check along the way if the value is not `nil` so I don't unexpectedly call methods on `nil` stuff unless I'm absolutely 100% sure that value can never be nil.

```
payments = @user.payment

if payments.count == 0
    some action
elsif payments.last.active_until.nil?
    some action
elsif payments.last.active_until.to_date > Time.now.to_date
    some action
end
```

or if you want to keep the same code you had then

```
if payments.count == 0
    some action
elsif !payments.last.active_until.nil? && payments.last.active_until.to_date > Time.now.to_date
    some action
elsif payments.last.active_until.nil?
    some action
end
```

Comment: I did, but them I only check until here elsif @user.payment.last.active_until.nil? but the field have this information active_until: "2013-01-24" so I don't undertand why the next if is never checked

Comment: If you're crashing on `undefined method `>' for nil:NilClass` then that means one of the values you have there is nil and I doubt Time.now.to_date is nil. How are you sure that @user.payment.last.active_until is not nil?

Answer (score 0):

Check your syntax in your model, including validations. All answers I've seen online concerning this type of error are just syntax errors. This error is essentially saying you're trying to call a comparison on the left-hand object, which happens to be nonexistent, so it's probably a problem with your model or validations.

Answer (score 0):

The only way that `to_date` will return `nil` is when you have a blank string.  All other strings will raise an exception of some sort.  You need to check for a blank string instead of `nil?` because `"".nil? == false`.  Instead, use `@user.payment.last.active_until.blank?`.  That will check for blank strings and nil.

```
if @user.payment.count == 0
    some action
elsif @user.payment.last.active_until.blank?
    some action
elsif @user.payment.last.active_until.to_date > Time.now.to_date
    some action
end
```

Besides that, is there any good reason that you're storing dates as strings?

Comment: No Sean, the field is not a string is a date, but I'm using a jquery calendar and change the dateformat to 'dd-mm-yy'